# Error 500 Symfony2

Tags: symfony, apache2

i have an error 500 when i load a webpage:

> An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (500: Internal Server Error). Do you want to open the profiler?

and the apache2 logs send this errors:

```
 [error] [client 192.168.13.119] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 42467328)         (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in /var/www/visual-immersion/path/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php on line 135, referer: http://local.visual-immersion.com/app_dev.php/
```

I increased the size of the memory 512, or 1024 in php.ini, well obviously rebooted the server, but without success.

I can not find where does the problem and it becomes quite hopeless. Tell me if you need more info (kernel config ...)
Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT: 
My general view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
        <meta name="description" content="toto ">
        <meta name="robots" content= 'index, follow'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}test {% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 id="main-title"><img src="" alt="logo"/> Title</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

My bundle view:

```
{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    Hello!
{% endblock %}
```

My controller Action:

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('visualimmersionVisualImmersionSiteBundle:Site:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Comment: That could be anything, like a circular include in your Twig templates...

Comment: Not really much information...I experienced that the real error lies deeper, the stacktrace is going to be so huge that it takes more and more RAM to even display it. My tip: temporarly setting the memory_limit to 1G or more and investigate the real error.

Comment: @PéCé i edited my initial post with views,in case you see something I would not have seen

Comment: Can you add your controller action, registered custom listeners (if you have), and your security configuration ?

Comment: @Sybio i added controller action.

Comment: Anything logged in app/logs/*.log ? How are named and where are stored your Twig "bundle view" and "general view" template files ? Did you not invert their names ?

Comment: @PéCé My bundle view is in visualimmersionbundle -> Resources -> views   -> site directory with name index.html.twig and the general view is in  App -> Resources -> View with name layout.html.twig.

Comment: Maybe a too big doctrine query?

Comment: I did some tests. I can make a layout bundle extends in my index. Or where the bug appears is when I try to do my extends from the general layout.

Comment: @Pazi for now, i just created my first views. No query.

Comment: Hi, I did some tests, and in prod mode, that's work. but in dev' mode, i have the error. i did clear the cache, modified the rights on the cache and logs directories. I really feel that the error comes from the general layout extends. Because if a delete the extends, that's work.

Answer (score 2):

try this also

clear the cache of symfony2 by using the following commands

```
php app/console cache:clear
chmod -R 777 app/cache
chmod -R 777 app/logs
```

Comment: I did it after each modification :s